# Linear Regression fit() speed up

Tags: python, performance, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I want to do Linear regression with a combination of numpy arrays (several millions) and would like to speed up this for loop:

```
from sklearn import linear_model as lm

LR = lm.LinearRegression()

for comb in combination:
    # comb is an numpy array with shape (200, 2) and y with shape (200,)
    R2 = LR.fit(comb, y).score(comb, y)
```

Is it possible run this in parallel?

Edit:
I have to split the dateset in combination of two and I have to track the best combination:

```
data = array([[ 0.1, 0.2,  0.3],
              [ 0.4 , 0.5, 0.6]])

combination = [[[ 0.1,  0.2], 
                [ 0.4 ,  0.5]],

               [[ 0.1,  0.3], 
                [ 0.4 , 0.6]],

               [[ 0.2,  0.3],  
                [ 0.5, 0.6]]])
```

The idea is to compare the R2 value for each combination and to return the combination with the best value.

```
column 1+2 -> R2 = 0.5
column 1+3 -> R2 = 0.2
column 2+3 -> R2 = 0.09
```

Comment: What are you tring to accomplish by that? is comb a subset of combination? Do you want to simulate cross validations ?

Comment: Comb is a subset of combinations and I try to compare the R2 score of each combination to find the best score.

Comment: If you really want to try these combinations, we do not have so much to compare but it should be still possible with gridsearch and a cv of 10, and since we only have 2 columns in each iteration, it should be relatively fast. However as I stated out you should also look at the permutation importance, It is possible that your model depends not on a combination but instead mostly on one column. Because of this you should try to also model perhaps a single linear regression instead of a multiple linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop for testing whether a train set will give you a best score or not, is not actually best practice, why you would not use the Kfold cross calidation:

First things first

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn import linear_model as lm


LR = lm.LinearRegression()
```

Now let's assume your train dataset name is `x_data` and test dataset is `y_data`

splitting the data into 10 sub data and then cross validate that

```
k_fold_lr = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=42)
scoring = 'accuracy'
lr_result_KNN = cross_val_score(LR, x_data, y_data, cv=k_fold_lr, scoring=scoring)
```

Then you can evaluation it:

`print(f'Accuracy=>{lr_result_KNN.mean()} Standard Deviation=>{lr_result_KNN.std()} \n')`

now you have a perspective of your model and results

if you didn't achieve your intended result you can change the number of subsets or change the percentage of the train set and data set

Comment: Thanks, I have to split the data in a specific way (see my edit). Is it possible with Kfold?

Comment: The efficient way is casting your array to Pandas DataFrame, then split your data to train set and test set and leave the rest to Kfold@honeymoon

Answer (score 0):

Robert is right. I would even strive to make a pipeline in finding the best fit while doing several cv. Changing subsets is not needed in this variant. our Random_CV will do enough. If you want to find the best solution, try GridSearchCV instead of randomized. But it will take longer

```
 from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, RandomizedSearchCV

    steps = [('Linear', LinearRegression())]
    pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
    params = {
        'Linear__someparameter':specific setting,
    }
    
    random_lin = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipeline, param_distributions=params, cv=10, random_state=0)
    
    random_lin.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    print(random_lin.score(X_test, y_test))
    print(random_lin.best_score_)
    print(random_lin.best_params_)
    
    pd.Series(permutation_importance(random_lin.best_estimator_, X_test, y_test, n_repeats=10)['importances_mean']).plot.bar()
```

Comment: I edit my question since I have to split my data in a certain way and to keep track. Not sure whether this is possible with GridSearch